# CollectionView Performance Improvement

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I've been sitting on this kind of problem for a while now, avoiding it. But I'm done now and decided I had to take it up front. Like many, I have a problem with my collection view performances and I'd like to know where it comes from and how to tackle it.

Maybe the Data template is too complex, maybe my binding method can be improved, or maybe the CollectionView approach is the wrong one altogether.

I build an app that reads WhatsApp Extracts, display some graphs and has the possibility to display chats messages from date A to date B. And, you guessed it, I'm displaying the chat messages in a CollectionView that yields awful performances : my device freezes for some seconds before displaying the CollectionView.

Some specific things :

- The items can vary in height (depending on the amount of text)
- Hundreds of items can be displayed in the CollectionView. I have the feeling it can be too much, but even something like 10 messages takes time to display

Here is my XAML :

```
<!-- List -->
            <StackLayout x:Name="slList">
                <CollectionView x:Name="cvChatLines" EmptyView="No chat lines">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" Fill="{Binding Background}" IsVisible="{Binding IsSender1}" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                                <Frame Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding Background}" BorderColor="White" CornerRadius="10" Padding="8" Margin="2" >
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"     Text="{Binding Sender}"      FontSize="Micro" />
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"     Text="{Binding Line}"        FontSize="Micro" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Message}"     FontSize="Micro" TextColor="White"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"     Text="{Binding DateTimeStr}" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Frame>
                                <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" Fill="{Binding Background}" IsVisible="{Binding IsSender2}" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
```

Basically, each data item is two ellipses displayed depending on the Sender, and a Frame containing a Grid in the middle to display the message itself.

It doesn't *seems* too complex, but the performances are awful. The loading itself takes a lot of time, and the scrolling is not top notch.

The binding operation itself is as simple as a cvChatLines.ItemsSource = filteredList;

I read here that one could "pre-tell" the size of the Collection View, but my data being variable in terms of length, it seems it can't be achieved.

I also read that one could load the full data chunk by chunk using events but, as a newbie, I have no clue on how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you measure the time to actually get the data (without dispalying it), just to verify that it is indeed a UI issue?

Comment: Quick question, and I hope you answer with "no". Are you testing performance in debug?

Comment: You have only sent us the GUI code and not the backend/app code. Without seeing more code, my guess is you are doing stuff on the UI thread that does not need to be done.

Comment: @Julian: To clarify: Moving logic to ViewModel does not automatically remove from MainThread. For example, button click handlers run on UI thread. There is nothing about being in ViewModel that can't be done exactly the same in View code behind; "MVVM" and "being on a background thread" are UNRELATED topics. Please stick to the question being asked.

Comment: The data gathering itself is quite long but I have it handled beforehand, with a progress bar. My App was designed to be a Tabbed one, but as I was one of my first (still learning) I didn't have multiple pages. So I used "Stacklayouts" that I'd show / hide depending on the page I want to show. The binding itself takes milliseconds, but it's when I want to display the "slList" (IsVisible = True) that it lags.
@H.A.H. : I tried launching using "Release" and wow, the performances are much better !
I pushed the project to GitHub : [link](https://github.com/Bebz0r/WhatsAppReader/)

Comment: What are you using `slList` for and when and how to do populate the `filteredList` that you assign as the `ItemsSource` to the CollectionView (`cvChatLines`)?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I am aware of that, but I expressed it wrong. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I removed the original comment.

Comment: @Julian : `slList` is my "List Page" that I display (I don't use specific xaml/cs for pages, but all my UI is in the MainPage. The sl is displayed when tapping the "List" tab - see [link](https://github.com/Bebz0r/WhatsAppReader/blob/master/WhatsAppReader/MainPage.xaml)

I populated `filteredList` by just applying filter on my main list which is loaded before hand (before the feeding of the Collectionview) : the ItemSource binding is separated from the whole data gathering process.

Comment: Could you please post the full log about this problem? And could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?